# What is select supposed to do if you close a monitored fd?

Tags: select, posix

I can test this to find the behavior but that's not the point. In [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882379/how-to-interrupt-a-fread-call/3883457#3883457) to another question, a commenter recommended closing a monitored fd from another thread to wake up `select`. Another commenter couldn't find a reference to this behavior in the standard, and I can't find one either.

Can someone provide a pointer to the standard on this behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the description of [select](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) in "The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7":

> A descriptor shall be considered ready for reading when a call to an input function with O_NONBLOCK clear would not block, whether or not the function would transfer data successfully. (The function might return data, an end-of-file indication, or an error other than one indicating that it is blocked, and in each of these cases the descriptor shall be considered ready for reading.)

So, I would say this method is portable.