# Unix: What happens when a read file descriptor closes while calling select()

Tags: c, unix

Say that I call select() on a FD_SET containing a bunch of read file descriptors. What happens if during the select() call, one of the file descriptor closes? Assuming that some sort of error occurs, then is it my responsibility to find and remove the closed file descriptor from the set?

Comment: Keep in mind that the only possible way a filedescriptor residing in a fd_set while you're inside the select() call can be closed is if another thread close() that descriptor. (having a tcp connection being closed by the peer or your local tcp/ip stack is another matter).

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3884110/what-is-select-supposed-to-do-if-you-close-a-monitored-fd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't believe this is specified anywhere; some systems may immediately return from `select` while others may continue blocking. Note that the only way this can happen is in a multi-threaded process (otherwise, the `close` cannot happen during `select`; even if it happened from a signal handler, `select` would have already been interrupted by the signal). As such, this situation arising probably indicates you have bigger issues to worry about. If one of the file descriptors you're polling can be closed during `select`, the bigger issue is that the same file descriptor might be reassigned to a newly opened file (e.g. one opened in another unrelated thread) immediately after the `close`, and the thread that's polling might then wrongly perform IO on the new file "belonging to" a different thread.

If you have a data object that consists of a set of file descriptors that will be polled with `select` in a multithreaded program, you almost surely need to be using some sort of synchronization primitive to control access to that set, and adding or removing file descriptors should require a lock that's mutually exclusive with the possibility that `select` (or any IO on the members) is in progress.

Of course in a multi-threaded program, it may be better not to use `select` at all and instead let blocking IO in multiple threads achieve the desired result without complicated locking logic.

Answer (score 1):

The `select()` system call takes three `fd_set` parameters: Send, Receive, Exception. To check, if an error occurs on a reading file descriptor include it in the read (receive) and in the error (exceprion) set - seeing it in the exception set on return from `select()` means, an exception has occurred on that socket, giving you the chance to find out what.

In general network sockets with any sort of exception will no longer be fit to send and receive.

Comment: Actually `exceptfds` are used for urgent data.

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/2/select as well as my experience say otherwise: *"those [file descriptors] in exceptfds will be watched for exceptions"*

Comment: I don't like promoting my answer but I did add a link and a quote.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you've read all the sent data, a closed socket is always regarded as ready to read. Select will unblock, signaling that socket to be available.