# Blocking on stdin makes Java process take 350ms more to exit

Tags: java

I have a Java program as follows:

```
public class foo{

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Thread t = new Thread(
      new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          try{System.in.read();}catch(Exception e){}
        }
      }
    );
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(10); // Make sure it hits the read() call
    t.interrupt();
    t.stop();
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

Running this (`time java foo`) with the `System.in.read` call present takes ~480ms to exit while running it with the `System.in.read` call commented out takes ~120ms to exit

I had thought that once the main thread reaches the end, the program terminates, but clearly, there's another 300ms lag hanging around (you can see this by adding a println after the `Thread.sleep`). I tried `t.interrupt` `t.stop` `System.exit` which should stop things "immediately", but none of them seem able to make the program skip it's 350ms extra exit latency seemingly doing nothing.

Anyone know why that is the case, and if there's anything I can do to avoid this latency?

Comment: Did you try to manually close file descriptor #0 (or it's corresponding input stream) and measure how much time does it take in presence of `System.in.read`? Maybe that what's happening on exit, not really sure.

Comment: Also, `time` util might be affected by opening/closing stdIn as it measures "The elapsed (real) time between invocation of **utility** and its termination." http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/utilities/time.html

Comment: `t.interrupt()` doesn't necessarily interrupts a thread immediately, `t.stop()` might not stop associated POSIX-threads. Interrupting stdIn in threads has its caveats as well (and it's system specific as some answers suggest): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008177/java-how-to-abort-a-thread-reading-from-system-in (this is for `readLine`, but it seems the "interrupt-able IO" problem might persist for "read" too)

Comment: instead of using `time`, what about computing milliseconds inside you java directly?

Comment: 1. [`Thread.interrupt()` does not interrupt blocking I/O](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--). 2. [`Thread.stop()` is deprecated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop--). 3. The obvious solution is `System.in.close()` before `System.exit()`.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion, and `System.in.close()` causes the program to hang indefinitely instead of exiting after a delay

Comment: @EJP closing input stream is what’s happening anyways on exit, so calling it directly obviously wouldn’t make things faster. Sorry if my initial comment was misunderstood, what I meant is to instrument how much time does closing input stream takes as it probably waited for read to finish. However, it was only part of the problem as answers suggested.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As it turns out besides collecting bad news, there is some workaround too, see the very bottom of this post.

<strike>This is not a full reply, just</strike> a check popped into my mind, with sockets.
Based on this and the `System.in.read()` experiment I have reproduced too, the delay may be the cost of having an outstanding synchronous I/O request towards the OS. (Edit: actually it is an explicit wait which kicks in when threads do not exit normally when the VM is shutting down, see below the horizontal line)

(I am ending the thread(s) with a `while(true);`, so it (they) never exits prematurely)

- if you create a bound socket `final ServerSocket srv=new ServerSocket(0);`, exit remains 'normal'
- if you `srv.accept();`, you suddenly have the extra wait
- if you create an "inner" daemon thread with `Socket s=new Socket("localhost",srv.getLocalPort());`, and `Socket s=srv.accept();` outside, it becomes 'normal' again
- however if you invoke `s.getInputStream().read();` on any of them, you have the extra wait again
- if you do it with both sockets, extra wait extends a bit longer (much less than 300, but consistent 20-50 ms for me)
- having the inner thread, it is also possible to get stuck on the `new Socket(...);` line, if `accept()` is not invoked outside. This also has the extra wait

So having sockets (just bound or even connected) is not a problem, but waiting for something to happen (`accept()`, `read()`) introduces something.

Code (this variant hits the two `s.getInputSteam().read()`-s)

```
import java.net.*;
public class foo{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    Thread t = new Thread(
      new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          try{
            final ServerSocket srv=new ServerSocket(0);

            Thread t=new Thread(new Runnable(){
              public void run(){
                try{
                  Socket s=new Socket("localhost",srv.getLocalPort());
                  s.getInputStream().read();

                  while(true);
                }catch(Exception ex){}
            }});
            t.setDaemon(true);
            t.start();

            Socket s=srv.accept();

            s.getInputStream().read();

            while(true);
          }catch(Exception ex){}
        }
      }
    );
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

I also tried what appears in the comments: having access (I just used `static`) to `ServerSocket srv`, `int port`, `Socket s1,s2`, it is faster to kill things on the Java side: `close()` on `srv`/`s1`/`s2` shuts down `accept()` and `read()` calls very fast, and for shutting down `accept()` in particular, a `new Socket("localhost",port)` also works (just it has a race condition when an actual connection arrives at the same time). A connection attempt can be shut down too with `close()`, just an object is needed for that (so `s1=new Socket();s1.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",srv.getLocalPort()));` has to be used instead of the connecting constructor).

TL;DR: does it matter to you? Not at all: I tried `System.in.close();` and it had absolutely no effect on `System.in.read();`.

---

New bad news. When a thread is in native code, and that native code does not check for 'safepoint', one of the final steps of the shutdown procedure [waits for 300 milliseconds](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/runtime/vm_operations.cpp#L397), minimum:

> ```
> // [...] In theory, we
> // don't have to wait for user threads to be quiescent, but it's always
> // better to terminate VM when current thread is the only active thread, so
> // wait for user threads too. Numbers are in 10 milliseconds.
> int max_wait_user_thread = 30;                  // at least 300 milliseconds
> ```

And it is waiting in vain, because the thread is executing a simple `fread` on `/proc/self/fd/0`

While `read` (and `recv` too) is wrapped in some magical `RESTARTABLE` looping thing (https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/os/linux/vm/os_linux.inline.hpp#L168 and `read` is a bit lower - it is a wrapper for `fread` in yet another file), which seems to be aware of `EINTR`

> ```
> #define RESTARTABLE(_cmd, _result) do { \
>     _result = _cmd; \
>   } while(((int)_result == OS_ERR) && (errno == EINTR))
>
> [...]
>
> inline size_t os::restartable_read(int fd, void *buf, unsigned int nBytes) {
>   size_t res;
>   RESTARTABLE( (size_t) ::read(fd, buf, (size_t) nBytes), res);
>   return res;
> }
> ```

, but that is not happening anywhere, plus there are some comments here and there that they did not want to interfere with libpthread's own signalling and handlers. According to some questions here on SO (like [How to interrupt a fread call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3882379/how-to-interrupt-a-fread-call)), it might not work anyway.

On the library side, `readSingle` (https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/share/native/java/io/io_util.c#L38) is the method which has been invoked:

> ```
> jint
> readSingle(JNIEnv *env, jobject this, jfieldID fid) {
>     jint nread;
>     char ret;
>     FD fd = GET_FD(this, fid);
>     if (fd == -1) {
>         JNU_ThrowIOException(env, "Stream Closed");
>         return -1;
>     }
>     nread = (jint)IO_Read(fd, &ret, 1);
>     if (nread == 0) { /* EOF */
>         return -1;
>     } else if (nread == JVM_IO_ERR) { /* error */
>         JNU_ThrowIOExceptionWithLastError(env, "Read error");
>     } else if (nread == JVM_IO_INTR) {
>         JNU_ThrowByName(env, "java/io/InterruptedIOException", NULL);
>     }
>     return ret & 0xFF;
> }
> ```

which is capable of handling 'being interrupted' on JRE level, but that part just will not get executed as `fread` does not return (in case of everything non-Windows, that `IO_Read` is [`#define`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-jdk/blob/master/src/solaris/native/java/io/io_util_md.h#L61)-d to `JVM_Read`, and that is just a [`wrapper`](https://github.com/openjdk-mirror/jdk7u-hotspot/blob/master/src/share/vm/prims/jvm.cpp#L2503) for the `restartable_read` mentioned earlier)

So, it is by design.

One thing which works is to provide your own `System.in` (despite of being `final` there is a `setIn()` method for this purpose, doing the nonstandard swap in JNI). But it involves polling, so it is a bit ugly:

```
import java.io.*;
public class foo{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    System.setIn(new InputStream() {
      InputStream in=System.in;
      @Override
      public int read() throws IOException {
        while(in.available()==0)try{Thread.sleep(100);}catch(Exception ex){}
        return in.read();
      }
    });

    Thread t = new Thread(
      new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          try{
            System.out.println(System.in.read());
            while(true);
          }catch(Exception ex){}
        }
      }
    );
    t.setDaemon(true);
    t.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
  }
}
```

With the `Thread.sleep()` inside `InputStream.read()` you can balance between being unresponsive or cooking with the CPU. `Thread.sleep()` correctly checks for being shut down, so even if you put it up to 10000, the process will exit fast.

Comment: Oh my god, I've had this issue for a while and I thought it was something i introduced. I have TCP serializer with the problems you described here. Is there really no way to prevent this 350ms on your scenario?

Comment: @A.A while honestly I do not fully understand where this delay causes actual problems (delay in a process which is terminating?), a thing which pops into my mind is explicitly closing the sockets (or even providing a dummy connection for the accept). While this will take some time too, remaining on the Java "side" may end up being faster than relying on this implicit request-cancelling mechanism.

Comment: @A.A good new to you, bad news to OP. ```Socket``` things can be shut down fast from Java side with a ```close()```, but it does not apply to ```System.in```

Answer (score 9):

As others have commented, Thread interrupt does not cause a blocking I/O call to immediately stop. The wait is happening because system in is waiting on input from a File (stdin). If you were to supply the program with some initial input you will notice it finishes much faster:

```
$ time java -cp build/libs/testjava.jar Foo

real    0m0.395s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.008s
$ time java -cp build/libs/testjava.jar Foo <<< test

real    0m0.064s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.012s
```

If you want to avoid waiting on I/O threads, then you can check the availability first. You can then perform a wait using a method which is interruptable such as `Thread.sleep`:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        if (System.in.available() > 0) {
            System.in.read();
        }
        Thread.sleep(400);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {

    }
}
```

This program will exit quickly each time:

```
$ time java -cp build/libs/testjava.jar Foo

real    0m0.065s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.008s
$ time java -cp build/libs/testjava.jar Foo <<< test

real    0m0.065s
user    0m0.040s
sys     0m0.008s
```